# Using collection object to store matches from Recordset in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sqlite, collections, recordset

Using Excel VBA, I am trying to search through an SQLite table for names that appear in a filename.

In the code below, I have the NamesFound collection object to store the names.

When I loop through the recordset, I can add names to NamesFound and print them.

After the recordset is closed and variables are destroyed, when I print the number of items in the collection (NamesFound.count), I get a number that matches the number of matching names in the filename.

However, when I try to print any of the elements in the collection, I get the error message "Object is no longer valid".

Any idea why this happens?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SQLiteMatch()

    Dim strSQL As String, fn As String
    
    Dim NamesFound As Collection
    Set NamesFound = New Collection
    
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    fn = "C:\Clark Gable & Vivian Leigh in Gone With The Wind.mp4"
    
    conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\Path\To\cast&crew.db;"
    
    strSQL = "SELECT id, person_name from People"
    
    rst.Open strSQL, conn, 1, 1
    
    With rst
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            If InStr(1, fn, ![person_name]) > 0 Then
                NamesFound.Add ![person_name]
                Debug.Print "Names found: " & NamesFound.Count & " - " & _
                    NamesFound(NamesFound.Count)                                '<<< Works fine
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    
    rst.Close
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print NamesFound(1) '<<< Error #3420: Object is no longer valid -
                              ' same error for NamesFound.item(1) and NamesFound(1).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with using a Collection](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?646681-RESOLVED-Problem-with-using-a-Collection)

Comment: Алексей Р Yes, that solution worked as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
...
'copy ![person_name] to a variable before adding to the Collection      Dim personNameCopy As String        With rst            .MoveFirst          Do Until .EOF
        personNameCopy = ![person_name]
        If InStr(1, fn, personNameCopy ) > 0 Then
            NamesFound.Add personNameCopy 
            Debug.Print "Names found: " & NamesFound.Count & " - " & _
                NamesFound(NamesFound.Count)                                '<<< Works fine
        End If
        .MoveNext           Loop        End With
...
```

The `rst` variable is set to `Nothing` before the last `Debug.Print` is executed and may have an effect on the `![person_name]` reference added to the Collection.